# Exibir qtd de números lidos, média, maior e menor valor lido

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
qtdNumeros = int(input())
if qtdNumeros <= 0:
    menor = "Nenhum"
    media = "Nenhuma"
    maior = "Nenhum"
else:
    menor = maior = soma = float(input())
    for proximo in range(1, qtdNumeros):
        valor = float(input())
        soma += valor
        if valor < menor:
            menor = valor
        elif valor > maior:
            maior = valor
    media = soma / qtdNumeros
print("Menor Lido:", menor)
print("Média dos Lidos:", media)
print("Maior Lido:", maior)
```

Ao invés de passar uma quantidade de números que ele vai ler e exibir a media, o menor e maior, gostaria de inserir números até que uma linha vazia fosse digitada, e também, exibir a quantidade de números que foram lidos.
Como posso implementar isso?

Answer (score 0):

É algo como isso que você deseja ?

```
import os

numbers = []

while True:
    os.system("cls") # Esse comando só serve para limpar a tela, então ignore caso você ainda não conheça sobre o módulo "os"

    num = input("\n Digite um número: ")
    if not num: break #Sai do bloco caso o usuário apenas aperte ENTER

    num = float(num) 
    numbers.append(num) # Acrescenta o número à lista de números
    numbers.sort() # Organiza os números na lista em ordem crescente

    # Calcula a média dos números inseridos
    media = 0
    for num in numbers:
        media += num
    media /= len(numbers)

    input("\n Maior número: {} \n Menor número: {} \n Média: {}".format(numbers[-1],numbers[0],media))
```

Talvez você não tenha aprendido ainda sobre listas, mas o que eu fiz nesse código foi colocar todos os números dentro de uma sequência, na qual, será organizada de tal forma que os números fiquem em ordem crescente. Após isso basta eu pegar o valor do primeiro elemento da lista e do último elemento da lista. E em relação a média, eu apenas fiz o cálculo percorrendo e somando cada valor da lista e no final eu dividi pela quantidade de elementos na lista.